# Code igniter validation- Ajax, error:function work while validation->run is true

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, validation

Hi I try to make validation form with ajax. When Textbox is empty, There is no problem everything works fine and give right errors. But when I fill in form Ajax else is not working and it goes to error:function . Please could you help!
When I enable  dataType:"JSON", 
I see output
false
Basvuru:1379 {isim: "

İsim Zorunludur!

", soyad: "

Soyad Zorunludur!

", emailadresi: "

Email Adresi Zorunludur!

", ilce: "", il: "", …}

When I disable   dataType:"JSON", ı could see console.log(data) of post datas otherwise goesto error:function

controller:

```
function basvuru_ekle()
    {


    $this->form_validation->set_rules('isim', 'İsim', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('soyad', 'Soyad', 'required' );
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('emailadresi', 'Email Adresi', 'required' );
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('ilce', 'İlçe', 'required' );
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('il', 'İl', 'required' );
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('adres', 'Adres', 'required' );
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('kordinat', 'Kordinat', 'required' );

    //$this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('Hata:', '');
    $this->form_validation->set_message('required', ' {field} Zorunludur!');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {

        $data = array(
            'isim' => form_error('isim'),
            'soyad' => form_error('soyad'),
            'emailadresi' => form_error('emailadresi'),
            'ilce' => form_error('ilce'),
            'il' => form_error('il'),
            'adres' => form_error('adres'),
            'kordinat' => form_error('kordinat'),
            'status'=> FALSE

        );

        echo json_encode($data);

    } 
    else {

            $basvurubiletnumarasi = strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S");
            $basvurudurumu = "1";

            $data = array(
                'basvurubiletnumarasi' => $basvurubiletnumarasi,
                'isim' => $this->input->post('isim') ,
                'soyad' => $this->input->post('soyad') ,
                'emailadresi' => $this->input->post('emailadresi') ,
                'ilce' => $this->input->post('ilce') ,
                'il' => $this->input->post('il') ,
                'ilce' => $this->input->post('ilce') ,
                'adres' => $this->input->post('adres') ,
                'kordinat' => $this->input->post('kordinat') ,
                'basvurudurumu' => $basvurudurumu,

                // 'olusturulmatarihi' => $this->input->post('olusturulmatarihi'),

            );


        $insert = $this->basvuru_model->basvuru_ekle($data);
        echo $data=json_encode(array("status" => TRUE));


        }
    }
```

View Ajax:

```
function save()
       {
         var url;
         if(save_method == 'add')
         {
             url = "<?php echo site_url('index.php/basvuru/basvuru_ekle')?>";
         }
         else
         {
           url = "<?php echo site_url('index.php/basvuru/basvuru_guncelle')?>";
         }

          // ajax adding data to database

              $.ajax({
              type:"POST",
              url:url,
              data:$('#form').serialize(),
             dataType:"JSON",
              success:function (data) {
              //  var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
            //  $('#data1').html(data);
            $('#isim1').html(data.isim);
            $('#soyad1').html(data.soyad);
            $('#emailadresi1').html(data.emailadresi);
            $('#ilce1').html(data.ilce);
            $('#il1').html(data.il);
            $('#adres1').html(data.adres);
            $('#kordinat1').html(data.kordinat);

              console.log(data.status);
               // alert(data.sonuc);

              if(data.status){
                console.log("false");

              }
              else{
                console.log("true");
               console.log(data);
              }


              },
              error:function(data){
                console.log("error");
              }

        }); 



       }
```

model:

```
function basvuru_ekle($data)
    {
    print_r($data);
    $this->db->insert($this->table, $data);
    return $this->db->insert_id();
    }
```

Comment: is the data properly inserting into the database? also remove this `print_r($data);` it will corrupt your json output.

Comment: Yes data is inserting to mysql database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `print_r()` in insert function and try this:

```
function save() {
    var url;
    if (save_method == 'add') {
        url = "<?php echo site_url('index.php/basvuru/basvuru_ekle')?>";
    } else {
        url = "<?php echo site_url('index.php/basvuru/basvuru_guncelle')?>";
    }

    // ajax adding data to database

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: $('#form').serialize(),
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data) {

            if (data.status == false) {
                console.log('false');
                $('#isim1').html(data.isim);
                $('#soyad1').html(data.soyad);
                $('#emailadresi1').html(data.emailadresi);
                $('#ilce1').html(data.ilce);
                $('#il1').html(data.il);
                $('#adres1').html(data.adres);
                $('#kordinat1').html(data.kordinat);
            } else {
                console.log("true");
            }
        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log("error");
        }

    });



}
```

Comment: Thanks For reply,
I got below console result when I fill in all blanks

console.log("error");

Comment: can you take a screenshot of the network response panel  in dev tools for the request?

Comment: See at the bottom of the list "basvuru_ekle"? Click that. Then you will see tabs. Take screenshot of the "response" one

Comment: Thanks for quick reply :)  
There is only {"status":true} on response tab but when I click 2 times basvuru_ekle ı got below 
{"isim":"","soyad":"","emailadresi":"","ilce":"","il":"","adres":"","kordinat":"","status":false}

Comment: try to change `echo $data=json_encode(array("status" => TRUE));` by remove `$data=` as it isn't necessary. here is what you should do: reload the page then open dev tools and go to network. it should be blank. type or do not type in the fields and submit the form. you should see the "basvuru" page request. click that and go to response. is it still blank?

Comment: Please Could you check ı edit last comment. I got {"status":true} in response

Comment: Oh my bad only read second part. I'm not seeing the issue. If it is giving that response it shouldn't enter the error of ajax function especially since you aren't getting a 404. Are you still able to replicate it?

Comment: Yes I erased $data=   and in response I get 
1
2
3  {"status":true}
And  when double click basvuru_ekle   I get 
{"isim":"","soyad":"","emailadresi":"","ilce":"","il":"","adres":"","kordinat":"","status":false}

Comment: Where is the 123 coming from?

Comment: could be the reason why you aren't getting a valid json back perhaps. are you echoing or print_ring or printing empty things elsewhere? like echo "";? sometimes people add it in config or random places and this can cause an issue with json output as it has to be pure json.

Comment: I checked all but no extra echo.  
When I disable this // dataType:"JSON",  console.log returns true from ajax 
else {
                console.log("true");
            }

Comment: yea but you should'nt have to disable it. esp since you are returning json. put this as error function: `error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                            if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                                alert('AJAX page not found.');
                            } else {
                                alert('AJAX Error: ' + textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);
                            }
                        }`

Comment: Thank you alex for your quick answers. I dont know how but after I copy your error:function  now everything works fine. I erased error:function to check it might the problem but it works again without error:function. Thank you for your support

Comment: After  removing print_r() which located in model. It works fine.

Comment: Wasn't that the first thing I suggested? ;)

Answer (score 0):

I checked to find the exact problem.As Alex said problem was because of Print_r() in modal. After I erased it ,now it works fine.
After fixed the problem.
view:

```
function save()
       {
         var url;
         if(save_method == 'add')
         {
             url = "<?php echo site_url('index.php/basvuru/basvuru_ekle')?>";
         }
         else
         {
           url = "<?php echo site_url('index.php/basvuru/basvuru_guncelle')?>";
         }

          // ajax adding data to database

              $.ajax({
              type:"POST",
              url:url,
              data:$('#form').serialize(),
             dataType:"JSON",
             success: function(data) {
               if (data.status == false) {
                 console.log('false');
                 $('#isim1').html(data.isim);
                 $('#soyad1').html(data.soyad);
                 $('#emailadresi1').html(data.emailadresi);
                 $('#ilce1').html(data.ilce);
                 $('#il1').html(data.il);
                 $('#adres1').html(data.adres);
                 $('#kordinat1').html(data.kordinat);
                 } else {
                   console.log("true");
                   $('#modal_form').modal('hide');
                   location.reload();// for reload a page
                   }
                   },
                   error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                     if (jqXHR.status == 404) { alert('AJAX page not found.'); 
                     } 
                     else { 
                       alert('AJAX Error: ' + textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown); } 
                       }
                       }); 



       }
```

controller:

```
function basvuru_ekle()
    {


    $this->form_validation->set_rules('isim', 'İsim', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('soyad', 'Soyad', 'required' );
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('emailadresi', 'Email Adresi', 'required' );
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('ilce', 'İlçe', 'required' );
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('il', 'İl', 'required' );
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('adres', 'Adres', 'required' );
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('kordinat', 'Kordinat', 'required' );

    //$this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('Hata:', '');
    $this->form_validation->set_message('required', ' {field} Zorunludur!');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {

        $data = array(
            'isim' => form_error('isim'),
            'soyad' => form_error('soyad'),
            'emailadresi' => form_error('emailadresi'),
            'ilce' => form_error('ilce'),
            'il' => form_error('il'),
            'adres' => form_error('adres'),
            'kordinat' => form_error('kordinat'),
            'status'=> FALSE

        );
        echo json_encode($data);

    } 
    else {

            $basvurubiletnumarasi = strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S");
            $basvurudurumu = "1";

            $data = array(
                'basvurubiletnumarasi' => $basvurubiletnumarasi,
                'isim' => $this->input->post('isim') ,
                'soyad' => $this->input->post('soyad') ,
                'emailadresi' => $this->input->post('emailadresi') ,
                'ilce' => $this->input->post('ilce') ,
                'il' => $this->input->post('il') ,
                'ilce' => $this->input->post('ilce') ,
                'adres' => $this->input->post('adres') ,
                'kordinat' => $this->input->post('kordinat') ,
                'basvurudurumu' => $basvurudurumu,

                // 'olusturulmatarihi' => $this->input->post('olusturulmatarihi'),

            );



        $insert = $this->basvuru_model->basvuru_ekle($data);
        echo json_encode(array(
            "status" => TRUE,
        ));


        }
    }
```

model:

```
function basvuru_ekle($data)
    {

    $this->db->insert($this->table, $data);
    return $this->db->insert_id();
    }
```